# April 2023 - Hexagons

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

*The final answer is 11 letters.*

[image: April 2023]

Helpful notes:

- *Technically solvable in grayscale/colorblind, but easier in color.*
- *If you have the required [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge), the solution path will eventually pop into your head; if you don't, it probably won't. So this is a good one to think about casually in the shower or on the road, rather than poring over dictionaries.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

April 1, 2023

> Rest in peace **[Klaus Teuber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaus_Teuber)**, creator of the board game [Settlers of Catan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catan)

The hexagons

> represent the hexagonal tiles in the board game.

The different colors

> represent the different types of tiles and the resources they provide. Arrows point from the tile type to the resource it provides.
>  [image]
>  The desert does not provide any resources.

Reading down the dotted hexagons

> yields the creator's name **Klaus Teuber**

Disclaimer

> This answer was inspired by @user118161's comment on another answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have spent quite a bit of time thinking about this and I have one note (maybe a very tiny partial fraction of a solution) and one question.

First, some assumptions I am making:

> 1. There should be one letter in each hexagon
>  2. The 11-letter solution will be the letters in the column with the black dots in
>  3. The colours of the rows don't have any specific meaning other than making it easier to see which rows the arrows connect
>  4. Each row will be a valid word
>  5. The arrows mean that the "source" row can be inserted into the "destination" row at the place indicated and make another valid word, for example the 7-letter light green row can be inserted at the start of the 4-letter light green row to make a valid 11-letter word

The note that might be a tiny part of a solution:

> The only word I can think of for the bottom row, that is a valid 6-letter word that is also a valid 7-letter word when an X is added to the end of it, is SIMPLE / SIMPLEX.
>  This would mean that the 11-letter solution ends in L. There is such a word which relates to hexagons, namely APICULTURAL, but I have no other evidence for this being the answer.

And the question:

> I'm bothered about the fact that the arrows on the hexagons come from / go to different aspects of the shape (the two left hand arrows and the one at the bottom pointing to X go from and to vertical edges of the hexagons, but this is not true for the other three on the right). Is this significant?

Based on the comments,

> I notice that the first few rows at least could be months:
>  (red) March
>  (lime) June
>  (yellow) April
>  (brown) September
>  (red) ?
>  (green) ?
>  (brown) May
>  (lime) August / October
>  (green) ?
>  (yellow) August / October
>  (tan) August / October
>  Doesn't work so well for the later ones, could those be days / dates / something else?

If I'm right about the first three rows that would be an 11 letter word starting

> HER

Such as...

> hereinafter
>   hermeneutic
>   herringbone
>   herpesvirus
>   herbivorous
>   hereinabove
>   herpetology
>   herrenvolks
>   heroicizing
>   hereinbelow
>   heresiarchs
>   herbivories
>   herbologies
>   hermeticism
>   herniations
>   heretically

Comment: I've been looking at this one a lot too. My own theory is that no 'insertion' is involved, but rather rot13(gur whfg-inthryl-cynprq neebjf vaqvpngr gung gjb ragevrf sbez n 'cnve' va fbzr jnl. Guvf jbhyq tvir hf fvk cnvef va gbgny (vapyhqvat gur zvffvat jbeq), juvpu vf na vqrny ahzore sbe n chmmyr nyy nobhg fvk-fvqrq urkntbaf. Cbffvoyl rira gur oynpx qbgf qba'g arprffnevyl vaqvpngr gur zvffvat jbeq ohg gur gurzr funerq ol gur fvk cnvef...). The month appearing in the title is puzzling me too - I'm assuming there must be a connection to current affairs, which I haven't yet spotted.

Comment: Na _beqrerq_ cnve, vf zl thrff.

Comment: @Stiv, Vicky - you are both partly correct and have spotted most of the clues. There is one more clue no one has called out. But I see the grayscale note was misleading and will update the puzzle.

Comment: @Amoz rot13(vz thrffvat 'qvpr' vf gur zvffvat pyhr, qhr gb gur qbgf naq gur tvira yrggref?)

Comment: @LukasRotter I thought of that too but couldn't make sense of the title.. rot13(Vf gurer fbzr qvpr eryngrq gbheanzrag tbvat ba znlor (Ncevy 2023)?

Comment: For what it's worth, I thought that rot13(gur neebjf vaqvpngrq beqrerq cnvef, gbb, naq gung gur frpbaq jbeq pbhyq or n zbagu, fb fbzrguvat Ncevy, fbzrguvat Znl.) That didn't get me anywhere, of course. I didn't think about (qvpr, ohg abj gung lbh zragvbarq gurz, V pna'g uryc ohg frr gur ebjf bs urkntbaf nf n [D*oreg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q*bert)-yvxr fgnpx bs phorf.)

Comment: August and October don't have the same number of letters. I'm not so sure the dotted hexes spell out a single word. It could be something like "Here is your ?", for example.

Comment: Could it be related to rot13(mbqvnp fvtaf creuncf, urapr jul guvf chmmyr frrz gb or zbagu eryngrq. Gur urkntbany cneg bs gur chmmyr zvtug or n qvfthvfrq jnl bs qrfpevovat "fgnef" va qvssrerag pbafgryyngvbaf. Nyfb gur mbqvnp fvtaf fgnegf jvgu Znepu naq n cbffvoyr jbeq sbe gur svefg ebj pbhyq or Znepu. Naq abgvpr gung nyy neebjf **cbvagf gb** ebjf jurer rnpu ebj unf n zbagu nf n cbffvoyr jbeq. Va beqre: Zne**p**u, Whar/Whyl, Nce**v**y, Znl, Nhthfg. V pbhyq or bss bsp ohg vg zvtug or fbzrguvat eryngrq gb fgne fvtaf).

Comment: All good guesses, but the information in the puzzle, especially the colors, is far more critical than the title. Also I apologize in advance that this puzzle leverages knowledge that is somewhat mainstream but not universal. It will either speak to you or it won't.

Comment: @MOehm goodness knows how I managed to convince myself that October has 6 letters, this shows how spending too much time on this kind of site can warp your mind :D

Comment: Does this have anything to do with civ 5/ catan 's hexagon tiles? the colors might be land types